# close all new tabs that matches an already opened tabs domain

Tags: javascript, regex, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Good morning,
I am trying to make this chrome extension that will close every new tab that matches a domain of an already open tab. Ive been trying and close as I got has been to close any new tab that matches a already open tab url exactly.

this is the script I got so far.

```
chrome.tabs.onCreated.addListener(function(newTab) {
    chrome.tabs.getAllInWindow(newTab.windowId, function(tabs) {
        var duplicateTab = null;
        tabs.forEach(function(otherTab) {
            if (otherTab.id !== newTab.id && otherTab.url === newTab.url) {
                duplicateTab = otherTab;
            }
        });
        if (duplicateTab) {
            chrome.tabs.update(duplicateTab.id, {"selected": true});
            chrome.tabs.remove(newTab.id);
        }
    });
});
```

so yeah, so basically if for example if a tab1 has open example.com then I would want this script to close any other tab that open with the same domain no matter  if the url does not match exactly.

Answer (score 1):

You could grab the domain from the otherTab.url using a [Regular Expression](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp) and use the [`.test()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_test.asp) method to see if it matches the newTab.url. This was a quick test that seems to be working as you are wanting.

```
chrome.tabs.onCreated.addListener(function (newTab) {
    chrome.tabs.getAllInWindow(newTab.windowId, function(tabs) {
        var duplicateTab = null;
        tabs.forEach(function(otherTab) {
            // Grab the domain from the otherTab
            var otherDomain = otherTab.url.replace(/(?:(?:http)s?:\/\/)?(.*?\..{2,3}(\..{2})?)(?:.*)/i, '$1');
            // Create a new RegEx pattern with it
            otherDomain = new RegExp(otherDomain, 'i');
            // Then test to see if it matches the newTab.url
            if (otherTab.id !== newTab.id && otherDomain.test(newTab.url)) {
                duplicateTab = otherTab;
            }
        });
        if (duplicateTab) {
            chrome.tabs.update(duplicateTab.id, {"selected": true});
            chrome.tabs.remove(newTab.id);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Seems like includes would be easier. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes

Comment: This is exactly what I was trying to do, works perfectly thanks or taking the time out and helping. Regex always been difficult for me for some reason.

Comment: `.addListener` is for older browsers. You might want to use `.addEventListener` instead.